# Android Socket Connection Refused ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I have created a server on my PC (localhost and port is 8080) and am trying to connect to it on my android device. But every time i try it gives me this error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

I have been looking online forever and looked at countless pages and have tried everything I could find.

-Switched the android host to 10.0.2.2

-Turned off firewall

-Changed the port

-Made sure both the PC and the android device where connected to the same internet connection

The Server code is written in Java and, just to make sure it works I tried making a connection to the server with another Java app. And it worked.

Thank you for your help, if you need any more info just let me know.

Comment: 1. Use other PC, run nmap and check it port is open
2. maybe your server listen only on localhost?
3. What server do you use?

Comment: @k.nieszporek Thank you for the reply. I am not using a server, i am using socket connections on  localhost. :)

Comment: I also got similar exception on one device (not emulator) only in Wi-Fi network and after upgrading an application. Clean install doesn't throw the exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use 10.0.2.2. That is for if your app runs on an emulator.

Use the LAN ip of your pc.

Find out with ipconfig.

Comment: What to try if this doesn't solve it? I have the same problem, but I do use the IP of the PC.

Comment: Check firewall. Or switch if off to test.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out now. I thought they were on the same network but they weren't. But thanks :)

Comment: even after using the LAN of PC, it is not working.